# Viewing Two (or Multiple folders) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, directory

Is it possible to have two "Current Folder" windows open in MATLAB?

I have two folders a long way away from one another in the folder tree and need to keep files in the same place as the are referred to by other software.

I should add that I am in the process of importing specific files from each one and cannot do all of one folder at once.

Comment: This is not a programming question!

Comment: Where should I ask it then?

Comment: I believe this question is within the scope of StackOverflow, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic :) This looks like a question which covers `software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development` :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no. You need to use commands like [`cd`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) to change from one folder to another for importing files, or add both folders to your MATLAB path using [`addpath`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html). The latter has the advantage of referring to any file in these folders without having to specify in which folder they are located.

Comment: I have been using `addpath` and it is very handy. `cd` is one i didn't know about and I think this will be helpful letting me switch between the two specifically. Thank you @am304